# Traefik - the server responded with a status of 502 ()

Tags: docker

I have installed the Traefik under docker using docker-compose
and I used the rules.toml file in order to redirect some request.

Trafick work well with the other docker (using SSL) installed on the same PC(it's a Qnap)

What I want it's just have a redirect like: 
https://router.domain.com 
Here is my rules.toml

```
########################### BACKENDS ####################################
[backends]
##### Router
[backends.backend-router]
[backends.backend-router.servers]
[backends.backend-router.servers.server-router-ext]
url = "http://192.168.1.1:4443"   ### https of router is set to 4443
weight = 0

#########################################################################
########################## FRONTENDS ####################################
[frontends]
##### Router
[frontends.frontend-router]
backend = "backend-router"
passHostHeader = true
[frontends.frontend-router.routes]
[frontends.frontend-router.routes.route-router-ext]
rule = "Host:router.domain.com"
```

And here is my traefik.toml file

```
InsecureSkipVerify = true
defaultEntryPoints = ["https", "http"]

# WEB interface of Traefik - it will show web page with overview of frontend and backend configurations
[api]
  entryPoint = "traefik"
  dashboard = true
  address = ":8080"
  usersFile = "/shared/.htpasswd"

# Force HTTPS
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

##########################################################################
# file rules.toml 
[file]
  watch = true
  filename = "/etc/traefik/rules.toml"

#############################
# Let's encrypt configuration
[acme]
email = "info@mymail.com"
storage="/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
acmeLogging=true
onDemand = false #create certificate when container is created
[acme.dnsChallenge]
  provider = "cloudflare"
  delayBeforeCheck = 0
InsecureSkipVerify = true
defaultEntryPoints = ["https", "http"]

# WEB interface of Traefik - it will show web page with overview of frontend and backend configurations
[api]
  entryPoint = "traefik"
  dashboard = true
  address = ":8080"
  usersFile = "/shared/.htpasswd"

# Force HTTPS
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

##########################################################################
# file rules.toml dove stanno i siti che non sono presenti nei vari docker
[file]
  watch = true
  filename = "/etc/traefik/rules.toml"

#############################
# Let's encrypt configuration
[acme]
email = "info@mymail.com"
storage="/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
acmeLogging=true
onDemand = false #create certificate when container is created
[acme.dnsChallenge]
  provider = "cloudflare"
  delayBeforeCheck = 0
```

When I try to access google chrome give this:

```
the server responded with a status of 502 ()
```

Can anybody please help me ? 
Thanks in advance

Denis